# Are virtual network interfaces useful outside of container usage?

Tags: networking, network-interface, veth

My networking background is limited.  I've been trying to understand more about VETHs, TUN/TAP, etc virtual network interfaces.  So far it seems that they make sense from a container perspective, but I can't see the advantage of their use at the host level.

Bridges makes sense, but I don't think they fall into the same category of VNIs.

Are virtual network interfaces useful outside of container usage?

Answer (score 0):

The `TUN` facility is commonly used for tunneling applications, like Virtual Private Network (VPN) systems.  Like the `TAP` device, this usually involves copying network data multiple times to and from user space.  Take a look at [OpenVPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN), for instance.

Virtual ethernet devices (`VETH`) on the other hand allow to redirect network packets inside the kernel.  This is incredibly useful in connection with routing rules, `iptables` kernel-based packet mangling, and the `tc` traffic shaper, for instance.